# Within a class: Calling a function with a function

Tags: php, class, methods

When I use the code below, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function passwordHash() in 
C:\(...)\index.php on line 38
```

If I do $something = new accountcreation;

and call it via $somethingn->passwordHash();, I'm able to call the function.

But, how do I call the function the way I want to, from within the class? (See the function: callMethods();)

Thanks.

```
class accountcreation {

    function __construct($passwordCreation, $userCreation, 
               $ipCreation, $emailCreation, $con) {
        $this->passwordCreation = $passwordCreation;
        $this->userCreation = $userCreation;
        $this->ipCreation = $ipCreation;
        $this->emailCreation = $emailCreation;
        $this->con = $con;

    }

     function callMethods() {
        passwordHash();
    }

     function passwordHash(){
        $this->passwordCreation = 
               password_hash($this->passwordCreation, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        var_dump($this->passwordCreation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `$this->passwordHash()`? :) In comparison to C++ you'll always have to explicitly name `this`/`$this`.